# Add 00 before a number to make it match required field

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to look up a matching employee number that is stored in 8 digits. the cells in XLS sheet vary some employees name have 5, 6 or 7 digits stored only in XLS. how do I pad 00 in front of the employees name that do not have 8 digits in their employee number.

Comment: Your question mentions 5, 6, or 7 digits, which would seem to imply that you want to fill leading zeros to a total of 8 digits.  The title and last sentence talk about 00, which would seem only applicable to 6 digit employee numbers.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function such as **TEXT** with a format mask **00000000** to pad any missing numbers to the left of the digit.

=TEXT(A1,"00000000")

[image: pad zero]

Source: [left padding zeroes in excel](http://jasonwhurley.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/left-padding-zeros-in-excel/)

Answer (score 0):

Custom format will do this.

Select all the cells or the entire column, right click and pick format cells.  Then set a custom format of "00000000" (eight zeros).  This will left pad zeros to make every entry 8 characters long.

Comment: But this will only cause the numbers to _display_ with leading zeroes. The question seems to concern matching 5-, 6-, and 7-digit numbers with numbers that are ***stored*** with eight digits somewhere else; I believe that your answer won't help with that.

Comment: The question didn't specify the use, in fact the questions says the numbers are stored only in the XLS.  It really depends on whether they want to format existing numbers or create a new entry in a new cell.

Comment: Well, I guess you and I are interpreting "I need to look up a matching employee number that is stored in 8 digits." differently.